# Google Cloud Translation Permission Denied - But has role

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I'm pulling my hair out over this and reaching out here for help. I'm trying to set up a service account with Cloud Translation, and Text-to-speech enabled, but we keep getting this response:

```
[error]  {
    "message": "Cloud IAM permission 'cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict' denied. ",
    "code": 7,
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": []
}
```

I have confirmed that the service account has the "cloudtranslate.generalModels.predict" permission, and showing the "Cloud Translation API User" role. We've also confirmed that it works with a different Service account that my colleague set up in his personal Google console profile. But, we need this setup with an account through our org.

I did verify that the service account has the permission from the [IAM Policy Troubleshooter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74448521/google-cloud-translation-permission-denied-but-has-role) so and that my organization's admin sees that the service account is granted access through ancestor policies.

So what else can we check?

Edit: Ok, turned out we had a hard-coded value for resource location, which was set to the wrong project. So of course it was coming back as permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turned out we had a hard-coded value for resource location, which was set to the wrong project. So of course it was coming back as permission denied.